# Increment number at end of string

Tags: vba, excel

My string is in the format `Cells(i, 6) & ("-000") & (q)`. Here `Cells(i,6).value` is an integer.

I want to add 1 to `q`, from the string it is in.

```
ElseIf k > 0 Then  
    Sht1.Cells(erow, 3) = CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 5).value) + 1  
    Sht1.Cells(erow, 4) = CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 6).value) + 1  
    Sht1.Cells(erow, 1) = Sht1.Cells(erow - 1, 1).value + 1   
End If
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: getting run-time error 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your code with this:

```
If k > 0 Then

    Sht1.Cells(erow, 3) = CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 5).value) + 1
    Debug.Print CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 5).value)

    Sht1.Cells(erow, 4) = CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 6).value) + 1
    Debug.Print CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 6).value)

    Sht1.Cells(erow, 1) = Sht1.Cells(erow - 1, 1).value + 1
    Debug.Print Sht1.Cells(erow - 1, 1).value

End If
```

And see where it breaks. Take a look at the immediate window. Probably the value is not a number.

If you edit the code a bit, you may get what you want:

```
Public Sub TestMe

If k > 0 Then

    Sht1.Cells(erow, 3) = IncreaseWithOne(sht3.Cells(i, 5).value)

End If

End Sub

Public Function IncreaseWithOne(strValue As String) As String

    Dim myVal  As Long

    myVal = Split(strValue, "-")(1)
    IncreaseWithOne = Split(strValue, "-")(0) & "-" & Format(myVal + 1, "0000")

End Function
```

But it is really better, if you edit your question to what you want. E.g., you want to split the string `25-00001`, cast to integer and increment the second part and return `25-00002`. Because adding integer to string is not supported by any programming language.

Comment: breaks on sht1.cells(erow,3) and getting the same error. My code looks like 16-00012

Comment: Then put on top of the line `    Debug.Print CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 5).value)` and tell what is in the immediate window.

Comment: It passes through 'debug.print and showing error on sht1.cells(erow,3)

Comment: What is the value, that is written in the immediate window?

Comment: When i use debug.print i am not getting any value in pop up box. But when i use 'msgbox (sht3.cells(i,5).value) then i get 25-0003

Comment: So, what do you expect to get from 25-003+1?

Comment: I want to add 1 every time elseif loop  execute.

Comment: And how much is `25-003` + 1?

Comment: I always want to add value after "-" sign. so 003+1

Comment: Then change your code to this: `    Sht1.Cells(erow, 3).text = CInt(sht3.Cells(i, 5).value) & "+ 1"`

Comment: With 'CInt(sht3.' i am getting the same error. But after removing 'CInt' from sht1.cells. But even am gettinh error 1004

Comment: `Sht1.Cells(erow, 3).text = sht3.Cells(i, 5) & "+ 1"`

Comment: On the same line or on the next line?

Comment: Eventually, after i remove '.text i am able to shift data to sht1. But my code is 25-0003+1. I want it to be 25-0004 @Vityata

Comment: Hi @Vityata, you should note that `.text` is read-only, so you cannot assign values to a range using it. Instead use `.value`. (Doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From your other question (linked at bottom), we know that the digits you want to increment are always the right-hand 4 characters, so you could use `Right` to isolate the numerical part. I also think you have now taken a different approach and are storing the increment value separately. For reference though, this is how you could have done it:

```
Dim myString as String
myString = "25-0003"

' Assume there is always a single dash before the number to increment
' This means we can use Split to create two parts, before and after "-"

Dim myVal as Integer
myVal = Val(Split(myString, "-")(1)) 
' >> myVal = 3

myVal = myVal + 1
' >> myVal = 4

myString =  Split(myString,"-")(0) & "-" & Format(myVal, "0000")
' >> myString = "25-0004"
```

So to edit your actual code, implementing the above code as a function, it becomes

```
Sub ThisIsYourSub()

    If k > 0 Then  
        Sht1.Cells(erow, 3) = IncrementString( sht3.Cells(i, 5).value )
        Sht1.Cells(erow, 4) = IncrementString( sht3.Cells(i, 6).value )  
        Sht1.Cells(erow, 1) = IncrementString( Sht1.Cells(erow - 1, 1).value)   
    End If

End Sub

Function IncrementString(ByVal myString as String) as String

    ' You should have some error handling in here!

    Dim myVal as Integer
    myVal = Val(Split(myString, "-")(1)) + 1

    IncrementString = Split(myString,"-")(0) & "-" & Format(myVal, "0000")

End Function
```

`Split` Documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528.aspx

---

Your other question, including details on using the `Format` function as above:

[Standard pattern of string is like 16-000q. Use leading zeros to create 4 digit string from q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675644/standard-pattern-of-my-code-is-like-16-000q-i-want-to-use-zeros-before-q-when/41675758#41675758)

Comment: If i want to MyString to a range of data it can be done in `split function `using compare feature?