# Standard pattern of string is like 16-000q. Use leading zeros to create 4 digit string from q

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, i am using

```
Cells(i, 6) & ("-000") & (q)
```

to generate my code. But I realise that when `q` becomes  a 2 digit int (i.e `11`), the output is like `16-00011`, which I don't want. I want the output to be like `16-0011`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `Format`:

```
Dim myOutput as String
myOutput = Cells(i, 6) & "-" & Format(q, "0000")

' If Cells(i, 6) = 16, and q = 11 then
' >> myOutput = "16-0011"

' If Cells(i, 6) = 16, and q = 9 then
' >> myOutput = "16-0009"
```

Documentation for `Format`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx